# Why don't Danger failures halt my CI build?

Tags: github-actions, danger

I'm running Danger as part of my lint/pre-compile on github actions. Here's a simplified version of the shell script call:

```
set -e
danger --dangerfile="dangerfile-pre-compile.rb"
```

Danger failures are triggering and showing up in the PR checks, but unfortunately my build keeps on rocking. Why doesn't this fail the build?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a shell script failure (a non-zero return value), `danger` should be called with `--fail-on-errors=true`, like so:

```
set -e
danger --fail-on-errors=true --dangerfile="dangerfile-pre-compile.rb"
```